# Property of PUSH-BUTTON in MATLAB GUI

Tags: user-interface, matlab, matlab-figure

In GUI's can i press same pushbutton twice/thrice/multiple times? I've designed a GUI with pushbutton, where it works only once at first when i pressed that.

```
function Flip_H_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
a = getimage(handles.axes1);
hflip = flipdim(a,2);
axes(handles.axes1);
    imshow(hflip);
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

above code is for `flip`. It flips image horizontally. However when i run this and if i press pushbutton image gets flipped but again if i press same button it do not! I thought like second time if i press it would call `Flip_H_Callback` again but its not like that. why is it so? What can i do for that?

Answer (score 1):

It will call the callback whenever you press the push button.

Your callback is not correct.

You never capture the output from `flipdim`, so whenever your callback executes it just flips the original matrix and show you the result what you got on first flip.

Instead use:

`a= flipdim(a,2);`

Also, its better to have a copy of initial image.